# Send GET request with FORM data

Tags: go

I need to sent GET http request with form data. I'm trying to do the following:

```
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, address, nil)

req.Form.Add("area_id", strconv.FormatInt(int64(areaId), 10))
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

But I receive crash - please explain how I can send GET request with FORM

Answer (score 0):

```golang
client := &http.Client{}

v := make(url.Values)
v.Add("area_id", strconv.FormatInt(int64(areaId), 10))

req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, address+"?"+v.Encode(), nil)
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

And access data using `r.URL.Query()` (`r` being `*http.Request`) in HTTP handler.